# HackerRank - Almost Sorted

Tags: c++, algorithm

I've written the following algorithm to solve [this HackerRank problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/almost-sorted/problem) using STL algorithms.

#### Problem statement

> Given an array with *n* elements, can you sort this array in ascending
>   order using only one of the following operations?
>
> 1. Swap two elements.
> 2. Reverse one sub-segment.
>
> Input Format
>
> The first line contains a single integer, n, which indicates the size
>   of the array.   The next line contains  integers separated by spaces.
>
> ```
> n  
> d1 d2 ... dn
> ```
>
> Output Format
>
> 1. If the array is already sorted, output yes on the first line. You do not need to output anything else.
> 2. If you can sort this array using one single operation (from the two permitted operations) then output yes on the first line and then:
>
>    - If you can sort the array by swapping d_l and d_r, output "swap l
>        r" in the second line. l and r are the indices of the elements to be
>        swapped, assuming that the array is indexed from 1 to n.
>    - Else if it is possible to sort the array by reversing the segment
>        d[l...r], output "reverse l r" in the second line. l and r are the
>        indices of the first and last elements of the subsequence to be
>        reversed, assuming that the array is indexed from 1 to n.
>
> d[l...r] represents the sub-sequence of the array, beginning at index
>   l and ending at index r, both inclusive.
>
> If an array can be sorted by either swapping or reversing, stick to
>   the swap-based method.
>
> 3. If you cannot sort the array in either of the above ways, output "no" in the first line.

#### Code

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    int n; std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(n);
    while(n--){
        int x; std::cin >> x;
        v.push_back(x);
    }
    auto v_sorted = v;
    std::sort(v_sorted.begin(),v_sorted.end());

    auto mismatch_1 = std::mismatch(v.begin(),v.end(),
                                    v_sorted.begin());
    auto mismatch_2 = std::mismatch(std::next(mismatch_1.first),v.end(),
                                    std::next(mismatch_1.second));
    auto mismatch_3 = std::mismatch(v.rbegin(),v.rend(),
                                    v_sorted.rbegin());

    if (std::prev(mismatch_3.first.base()) == mismatch_2.first) {
        if (*std::prev(mismatch_2.first)<=*mismatch_1.first) {
           std::cout 
               << "yes\n" << "swap " 
               << std::distance(v.begin(),mismatch_1.first) + 1
               << " "
               << std::distance(v.begin(),mismatch_2.first) + 1;
        }
    }
    else {
       std::reverse(mismatch_1.first,mismatch_3.first.base());
       if (std::equal(mismatch_1.first,std::prev(mismatch_3.first.base()),mismatch_1.second)) {
           std::cout
               << "yes\n" << "reverse "
               << std::distance(v.begin(),mismatch_1.first) + 1
               << " "
               << std::distance(v.begin(),std::prev(mismatch_3.first.base())) + 1;
       }
       else {
           std::cout << "no";
       }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### Questions

My main question is about reverse iterators. I feel it's a little bit confusing when I compare them with forward iterators, as I need to do `std::prev(reverse_iterator.base())`. Do you think this affects readability or is the code fine like it is? Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the reverse iterators a bit confusing, but I might be a little slow. That said, I'm probably not the only one, so you wouldn't waste your time looking for a simpler way to express yourself.

I'd add that you forgot to handle the case where the input is already sorted, meaning that you could have been overwhelmed yourself ;-)

My suggestion, using `std::adjacent_find` to detect sign changes (note that I use a reverse iterator only once, to denote the vector's last element -in that case it feels intuitive to me):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

void is_almost_sorted(std::vector<int>& vec) {
    // find swap candidates, swap and check if sorted
    auto first  = std::adjacent_find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::greater<int>()); // first sign change... 
    if (first == vec.end()) {
        std::cout << "Already sorted";
        return;
    }
    auto bkp = vec;
    auto second = std::adjacent_find(first+1, vec.end(), std::greater<int>()); // and second
    if (second != vec.end() 
        && (std::iter_swap(first, second+1), std::is_sorted(vec.begin(), vec.end()))) {
        std::cout << "swap " << *first << " and " << *++second;
        return;
    }
    // restore from original vec
    auto offset = std::distance(vec.begin(), first);
    vec = std::move(bkp);
    first = vec.begin()+offset;
    // find inverse change of signs, reverse and check if sorted
    second = std::adjacent_find(first+1, vec.end(), std::less<int>());
    std::reverse(first, second == vec.end() ? second : second + 1);
    if (std::is_sorted(vec.begin(), vec.end())) {
        std::cout << "reverse from " << *first 
                  << " to " << (second == vec.end() ? *std::rbegin(vec) : *++second);
        return;
    }
    std::cout << "no solution";
}
```

Comment: Oh, nice idea to use the adjacent_find! I always get so impressed about the ways to use the algorithms. One thing, you are outputting the value and not the position right? or am I missing something?

Comment: Small thing, `std::` is missing in the last if.

Comment: @WooWapDaBug edited that last if / yes, value not position, I might have read the assignment too quickly. But converting an iterator to a position is quite easy. / if you like the stl's algorithms you should check Sean Parent's conferences on youtube. I particularly like "Better code" (the "no raw loop" section is what you're looking for).

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference to Sean Parent's conferences! I'm really liking it!

Comment: Hackerrank seems to support only to c++14, what a pity.